# Regex look back format condition

Tags: regex

I need help to make a regex that can match specific format.

**Input:**

> "fr. 2 699:- 2 fr. 599:- 3 fr. 899:- 4 fr. 3 899:- 5 fr. 1 499:- 6 fr. 999:-"

**Output:**

> "599 899 999"

I have tried: `[1-9]\d{2}` but output are then "699 599 899 899 499 999"

I will test the result at http://rubular.com/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you define the logic behind your desired output? It's a bit tiring to start guessing whenever a new question pops up. Also what language are you using?

Comment: ok the logic behind is to find the "fr. 599", "fr. 899" and "fr. 999" and get the output "599 899 999". Did that answer?
The regex shall be working at http://rubular.com

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to match the numbers that follow `fr.`

The following regex should work:

```
fr\. ([1-9]\d{2})
```

Tested at:  http://rubular.com/r/ct5WD9TlTg

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

[**Online Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/vP0eX3)

```
/(?<=fr\.\s)(\d{3})/g
```

Comment: Escape the dot and remove group 1, it's not needed.

Comment: If input: "Hello fr. 2 699:- 2 fr. 599:- 3 fr. 899:- 4 fr. 3 899:- 5 fr. 1 499:- 6 fr. 999:-" ?

Comment: @user3214294 it seems it is matching your desired values

Comment: But where do i put "hello"?

Comment: @user3214294 Do you want to match hello?

Comment: No. "Hello" is just in the beginning of the input.

Comment: Input: "Hello fr. 2 699:- 2 fr. 599:- 3 fr. 899:- 4 fr. 3 899:- 5 fr. 1 499:- 6 fr. 999:-". Output: "599 899 999" . Where do I put in "Hello" in : /(?<=fr\.\s)(\d{3})/

Comment: "Hello" is pre-requiste for a match/output on "599", "899" and "999"

Comment: @user3214294 in most languages/regex engines, you need to specify a fixed length lookbehind, which in your case is clearly not fixed. So the easy solution would be to use two regexes: the first one to match a line with "hello", the second one is to match the digits.